# PostgreSQL 9.6 using case-when clause based on sum of the column

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

Here is create and insert script:

```
CREATE TABLE numbers (
  id integer NOT NULL,
  number1 integer NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO numbers (id, number1) VALUES
  ('1', '1'),
  ('2', '1'),
  ('1', '2'),
  ('1', '3');
```

if the sum of number1 column is even return its average, other wise return 0. So it should return [id:1, number1:0] for above example

I have tried this:

```
select id,
  case
    when sum(number1) %2=1 then 0 else avg(number1)
  end as number1
from numbers
```

it works fine with mySql but not for PostgreSQL (I used http://sqlfiddle.com to try it out).
error message in PostgreSQL is

```
 ERROR: column "numbers.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Comment: Everytime you SELECT a column while using aggregate functions, this column must be in the GROUP BY list. This is what the error is telling you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why the expected value of `id` is `1` and not `2`? Is this defined by the query in any way? MySql does not care about it, in contrary to Postgres (and other well known RDBMs).

If the value of `id` is negligible:

```
select
    case
        when sum(number1) %2 = 1 then 0 
        else avg(number1)
    end as number1
from numbers;

 number1 
---------
       0
(1 row)
```

If you want to get e.g. the smallest value of `id`:

```
select
    min(id) as id,
    case
        when sum(number1) %2 = 1 then 0 
        else avg(number1)
    end as number1
from numbers;

 id | number1 
----+---------
  1 |       0
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the id was an unimportant row and as you said it caused the problem.