# Remove column from SELECT clause when using SUM in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, select, group-by, enums, sum

I checked the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45129912/postgresql-9-6-using-case-when-clause-based-on-sum-of-the-column) but didn't solve my problem because I even adding the `else` still throwing the same error:

```
ERROR:  column table1.column11 must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

I would like to remove `table1.column11` from `SELECT` because is affecting the `GROUP BY`. Instead of each `ENUM` type be a column in a single line this query below is returning a table with a `ENUM` column filled in different lines.

Query example:

```
SELECT table1.column11, -- enum column
   table2.id,
   (case when table1.column11 = 'enum_value_1' then SUM(table1.column12) end) as enum_value_1,
   (case when table1.column11 = 'enum_value_2' then SUM(table1.column12) end) as enum_value_2,
   --- ...
   (case when table1.column11 = 'enum_value_9' then SUM(table1.column19) end) as enum_value_9,
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.table2_id
WHERE table1.column13 IS NULL
GROUP BY table2.id, table1.column11
ORDER BY table2.id ASC
```

---

How is now:

```
table1.column11 | table2.id | enum_value_1 | enum_value_2 | ... | enum_value_9
================|===========|==============|==============|=====|=============
enum_value_1    | 1         | 10           | [null]       | ... | [null]
enum_value_2    | 1         | [null]       | 20           | ... | [null]
...             | ...       | ...          | ...          | ... | ...
enum_value_9    | 1         | [null]       | [null]       | ... | 15
```

How I would like to have:

```
table2.id | enum_value_1 | enum_value_2 | ... | enum_value_9
==========|==============|==============|=====|=============
1         | 10           | 20           | ... | 15
```

Comment: @klim when you have time :) pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example in the question is difficult to reproduce, but I think my suggestions will be helpful. Remove `table1.column11` from the select list and use the column only inside the aggregates.

So instead of:

```sql
SELECT table1.column11, -- enum column
   table2.id,
   (case when table1.column11 = 'enum_value_1' then SUM(table1.column12) end) as enum_value_1,
```

use:

```sql
SELECT
   table2.id,
   sum(case when table1.column11 = 'enum_value_1' then table1.column12 end) as enum_value_1,
```

Comment: thanks @kiln worked just fine